# Can remember me functionality work when not using a login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use Remember Me functionality, without having to login?

Scenario:
User visits a mobile page, fills out some information then checks Remember Me. Then if the user goes back to the same page again a day or two later, that it populates the fields with the last information entered.
all this being done either on tablet or smartphone and without logging in.

Is this possible?

Comment: @KobyDouek  I never thought of that and wasn't really sure how that would work on smartphones. Now I know what to look around on

Comment: Store it somewhere and read it back as needed.

Comment: @Chris I provided an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a classic use of cookies in a website (mobile phone's browsers support them too).

After the user enters the information, store the values in a cookie:

```
HttpCookie Oreo = new HttpCookie("user");
Oreo.Values["name"] = userName;
Oreo.Values["email"] = userEmail;
Oreo.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(60);
this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(Oreo);
```

Then, in your page load code, check if the cookie exsits, if it does, you can get its stored values:

```
if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("user"))
{
    string name = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies["user"].Values["name"];
    string email = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Cookies["user"].Values["email"];
}
```

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: This answer is about cookies, which have nothing to do with ViewModel, ViewBag, etc.

Comment: Look the revision History @David

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Thanks for the highlight, I've updated my answer